# error TS2339: Property 'name' does not exist on type 'never'

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

**app.component.html**
as you can see I'm trying to show response data of my firebase project by *ngFor

```
<div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-3">
            <h4 class="text-warning">All Employee Data</h4>
            <div class="card" *ngFor="let item of employee">
                <div class="card-body">
                    <div class="card-title">
                        Name: {{item.name}} // error-Property 'name' does not exist on type 'never'.
                    </div>
                    <div class="card-subtitle">
                        Age: {{item.age}} // error-Property 'name' does not exist on type 'never'.
                    </div>
                    <div class="card-text">
                        Address: {{item.address}} // same error here also
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

**app.component.ts**
as you can see I'm trying to fetch data from firesbase project.

```
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  title = 'App';

 constructor( private _crudService:CrudService) {}

     employee:[] = [];
     employeeName: string = '';
     employeeAge: number | undefined;
     employeeAddress: string = '';
     message: string ='';

 ngOnInit(){
  this._crudService.getAllEmployee().subscribe((data:any) =>{
    this.employee = data.map((e:any) =>{   // here I'm storing res in empty array  
      return{
        id: e.payload.doc.id,
        name: e.payload.doc.data()['name'],
        age: e.payload.doc.data()['age'],
        address: e.payload.doc.data()['address']

      }
    });
    console.log(this.employee);
  }); 
 }
```

**crud.service.ts**
as you can see I'm sending request to get Employee Data

```
getAllEmployee(){
    return this.fireservice.collection('Employee').snapshotChanges();
  }
```

Comment: why you are not using `e.payload.doc.data.name` instead of  `e.payload.doc.data()['name']`  in ngOnInit

Comment: let me try.. if it's works, thank you in advance

Comment: no buddy , it doesn't work

Comment: your code is correct, may be you can check response from _crudService.getAllEmployee OR you can debug code for  `   this.employee = data.map((e:any) =>{ 
      return{
        id: e.payload.doc.id,
        name: e.payload.doc.data()['name'],
        age: e.payload.doc.data()['age'],
        address: e.payload.doc.data()['address']
      }
    });   `

Comment: yes, there is no issue in response i'm getting response like this. address: "Ahmedabad"
age: 21
id: "xS0Uz0eXCNyb4YciVadj"
name: "harsh"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Option 1: safe navigation operator

The array `employee` is empty when the component is rendered initially. You could use the safe navigation operator `?.` to check if a property is available before trying to render it.

```html
<div class="card-title">
  Name: {{ item?.name }}
</div>
<div class="card-subtitle">
  Age: {{ item?.age }}
</div>
<div class="card-text">
  Address: {{ item?.address }}
</div>
```

#### Option 2: `async` pipe

If the variable `this.employee` is used only to render the output in template, you could skip the subscription in the controller and use `async` pipe in the template.

**Controller**

```js
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { map, tap } from 'rxjs/operators';

export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  title = 'App';
  employees$: Observable<Array<any>>;        // <-- type observable here
  employeeName: string = '';
  employeeAge: number | undefined;
  employeeAddress: string = '';
  message: string = '';

  constructor(private _crudService: CrudService) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.employees$ = this._crudService.getAllEmployee().pipe(
      map((e: any) => ({
        id: e.payload.doc.id,
        name: e.payload.doc.data()['name'],
        age: e.payload.doc.data()['age'],
        address: e.payload.doc.data()['address']
      })),
      tap(console.log) // <-- check the value
    );
  }
}
```

**Template**

```html
<ng-container *ngIf="(employees$ | async) as employees">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-3">
      <h4 class="text-warning">All Employee Data</h4>
      <div class="card" *ngFor="let item of employees">
        <div class="card-body">
          <div class="card-title">
            Name: {{ item['name'] }}     <!-- bracket notation instead of dot notation -->
          </div>
          <div class="card-subtitle">
            Age: {{ item['age'] }}
          </div>
          <div class="card-text">
            Address: {{ item['address'] }}
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</ng-container>
```

Comment: no it doesn't work, throwing same error after navigation operator ?.

Comment: I'm getting response like address: "Ahmedabad"
age: 21
id: "xS0Uz0eXCNyb4YciVadj"
name: "harsh"

Comment: @harsh: Does the output get rendered even with the errors?

Comment: no output doesn't rendered. throwing error in compilation

Comment: It sounds like not a Linter issue. However you could try the bracket notation instead of dot notation. I've updated the answer for another method to get the results. Please see if it works for you.

Comment: Great my Buddy it Works... Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can use `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(data))` before
   `this.employee = data.map((e:any) =>{   // here I'm storing res in empty array`